# UserControl hosted in Panel

Tags: wpf

I've spent a lot of time with this problem. I have custom user control in wpf, It's toolbar with 10 buttons. This toolbar is added in Panel(winform panel) panel.Controls.Add(usercontrol). What I want is, respond on MouseLeave event from Panel. 
I've tried panel.MouseLeave += MouseLeaveEvent, but event hasn't raised. No one event isn't raised(MouseMove, etc.). Is there any solution, how to make it, that MouseLeave event will be raised?
Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Here is the code.

```
CustomToolbar = new AxisMediaControlToolbarViewModel(this);
                    var toolbarView = new AxisMediaControlToolbarView { ViewModel = CustomToolbar };
                    var elementHost = new ElementHost { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Child = toolbarView };
                    toolbarPanel.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

Comment: Please correct the title of your thread and the tags. WinForms is the "old framework" that is in .Net since .Net1.1/2.0. The WPF is the new framework. You seem to refer to WPF only, so WinForms should not be here. Also, the title does not describe what is the problem. The problem is rather "My WPF Panel in a UserControl does not see mouse events" etc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/4af591da-11aa-410b-8d1f-d4c08f96c382) are quite a few causes mentioned:

- Set the Background of the UserControl
- Make the Canvas focusable
- Be aware of RenderTransforms

**EDIT**

I made a test and it works fine as long as the WPF element is not covering the Panel. The mouse has to be DIRECTLY over the panel to generate the event. The DockStyle.Fill might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: But I want to raise mouseleaveevent of Panel, no events of WPFusercontrol

Comment: When the WPF element covers the Panel the MouseLeave event will only be raised on the WPF element and will not bubble up to the WinForms Panel. The ElementHost is NOT aware of child events. Could you post a picture that shows the ElementHost and WPF control?

Comment: I made a test and it works fine as long as the WPF element is not covering the Panel. The mouse has to be DIRECTLY over the panel to generate the event.

Comment: Yes, When WPF element is not in panel, the mouse events are firing.

Comment: When I haven't used DockStyle.Fill, it works, but only on place, where the control doesn't take up space. When I move over usercontrol and leave, event is not fired.

Comment: That is exactly what I wrote. You could apply a margin to the ElementHost so you'll always have the panel exposed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes may be that your panel's background is not set.

If you do not set the background, then the control is though to be as "its area is not to be taken care of" and effectively it is transparent, because it is not drawn. However, it has more consequences: it's area is not only not drawn, but also it is not tracked i.e. for mouse events.

For starters, try setting Background="Transparent". It may make little sense as it is already transparent, but this way the Panel control will **have** a background and if there are no other problems, it may immediatelly start seeing the mouse events.

edit: quickexample:

UserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlMouse.MyButtonPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Background="LightBlue"
             Tag="You will never see this message">

    <StackPanel Margin="20" Background="LightGray"
                MouseEnter="handler_MouseEnter" MouseMove="handler_MouseMove" MouseLeave="handler_MouseLeave"
                Tag="StackPanel">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button Content="#1" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#1" />
        <Button Content="#2" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#2"
                MouseEnter="handler_MouseEnter" MouseMove="handler_MouseMove" MouseLeave="handler_MouseLeave"
                />
        <Button Content="#3" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#3" />
        <Button Content="#4" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#4" />
        <Button Content="#5" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#5"
                MouseEnter="handler_MouseEnter" MouseMove="handler_MouseMove" MouseLeave="handler_MouseLeave"
                />
        <Button Content="#6" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#6" />
        <Button Content="#7" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#7" />
        <Button Content="#8" MaxWidth="80" Tag="Button#8" />

        <TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0" Tag="Comment TextBlock #1">
            <Run Text="Sender was: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding ReportingControl}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Tag="Comment TextBlock #2">
            <Run Text="Source was: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding ContainerControl}" />
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Tag="Comment TextBlock #3">
            <Run Text="Now you are in: " />
            <Run Text="{Binding ControlUnderMouse}" />
        </TextBlock>

        <UniformGrid Columns="3" Tag="indicator UniformGrid">
            <Border Visibility="{Binding Visib_OnEnter}" Tag="indicator border #1">
                <TextBlock Text="Enter" />
            </Border>
            <Border Visibility="{Binding Visib_OnMove}" Tag="indicator border #2"
                    MouseEnter="handler_MouseEnter" MouseMove="handler_MouseMove" MouseLeave="handler_MouseLeave">
                <TextBlock Text="Move" />
            </Border>
            <Border Visibility="{Binding Visib_OnLeave}" Tag="indicator border #3">
                <TextBlock Text="Leave" />
            </Border>
        </UniformGrid>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

usercontrol.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace UserControlMouse
{
    public partial class MyButtonPanel : UserControl
    {
        private SimpleDataObject theData = new SimpleDataObject();

        public MyButtonPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = theData;
        }

        private const int COUNTER_LAG = 20;

        private int counter_enter = 0;
        private void handler_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            counter_enter = counter_mouse;

            theData.Visib_OnEnter = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            theData.Visib_OnMove = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            theData.Visib_OnLeave = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

            theData.ReportingControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(sender);
            theData.ContainerControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(e.Source);
            theData.ControlUnderMouse = makeDescriptionOfControl(null);
        }

        private int counter_mouse = 0;
        private void handler_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ++counter_mouse;

            if (counter_mouse > counter_enter + COUNTER_LAG) theData.Visib_OnEnter = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            theData.Visib_OnMove = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            if (counter_mouse > counter_leave + COUNTER_LAG) theData.Visib_OnLeave = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

            theData.ReportingControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(sender);
            theData.ContainerControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(e.Source);
            theData.ControlUnderMouse = makeDescriptionOfControl(null);
        }

        private int counter_leave = 0;
        private void handler_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            counter_leave = counter_mouse;

            theData.Visib_OnEnter = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            theData.Visib_OnMove = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            theData.Visib_OnLeave = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

            theData.ReportingControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(sender);
            theData.ContainerControl = makeDescriptionOfControl(e.Source);
            theData.ControlUnderMouse = makeDescriptionOfControl(null);
        }

        private string makeDescriptionOfControl(object uiobj)
        {
            if (uiobj == null)
                return "???";

            string text = uiobj.GetType().Name;

            var fe = uiobj as FrameworkElement;
            if (fe != null && fe.Tag != null)
                text += " (" + (string)((FrameworkElement)uiobj).Tag + ")";

            return text;
        }
    }

    public class SimpleDataObject : DependencyObject
    {
        public string ControlUnderMouse { get { return (string)GetValue(ControlUnderMouseProperty); } set { SetValue(ControlUnderMouseProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ControlUnderMouseProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ControlUnderMouse", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata("???"));

        public string ReportingControl { get { return (string)GetValue(ReportingControlProperty); } set { SetValue(ReportingControlProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ReportingControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ReportingControl", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata("???"));

        public string ContainerControl { get { return (string)GetValue(ContainerControlProperty); } set { SetValue(ContainerControlProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContainerControl", typeof(string), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata("???"));

        public Visibility Visib_OnEnter { get { return (Visibility)GetValue(Visib_OnEnterProperty); } set { SetValue(Visib_OnEnterProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Visib_OnEnterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visib_OnEnter", typeof(Visibility), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));

        public Visibility Visib_OnMove { get { return (Visibility)GetValue(Visib_OnMoveProperty); } set { SetValue(Visib_OnMoveProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Visib_OnMoveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visib_OnMove", typeof(Visibility), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));

        public Visibility Visib_OnLeave { get { return (Visibility)GetValue(Visib_OnLeaveProperty); } set { SetValue(Visib_OnLeaveProperty, value); } }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Visib_OnLeaveProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Visib_OnLeave", typeof(Visibility), typeof(SimpleDataObject), new UIPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Hidden));
    }
}
```

sample window

```
<Window x:Class="UserControlMouse.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UserControlMouse"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <my:MyButtonPanel Margin="10" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please run it and play with it.

- Observe how the events are fired and which controls see them. Note how SENDER and SOURCE are changing
- note that SENDER is always the same, the root of the mouse-capture. It is the Source that changes
- **note that only button #2 and button #5 is reporting ENTER/LEAVE** (they have direct handlers, others have not!)
- note that other controls are 'detectable' with the mouse-move even if they don't have mouse handlers - you can get events with Source(s) that does not have any mouse capture set
- check the OriginalSource (the last text line) - this is the control directly under mouse - and often it is not the control you would want to notice, as it is some "leaf control" from some templates or styles..

Comment: Yes panel has background - white. But events are not firing.

Comment: See my example. It a whole window and a custom user control on it. The control presents in the real time what is currently under the mouse. The mouse events report three things: the Sender, the Source, and the leaf = OriginalSource. It also shows when Enter/Leave events occur with a slight delay, as Move events occur very often and without proper delay or styling, you'd simply not see the Enter/Leave.

Comment: Damn it! I've set background to the UserControl, not Panel, and it works finally!!! THANK YOU EVERYONE